# Slide bootstrap element inline

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

My problem is keeping prepended element (glyphicon) with existing text inline.

I have a text and when user hover it I prepend icon with slide effect from JQuery UI 1.10.2. But prepended icon push my text to new line.

This is my html:

```
<div class="hover-me">
  <h4>My title</h4>
</div>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('.hover-me').hover(function() {
     $('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; font-size: 15px;"></span>&nbsp;').prependTo($(this).find('h4')).toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 400);
}, 
function() {
    $(this).find('.glyphicon').hide().toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 400);
});
```

I have made some example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pza9tmg8/) too.

The second problem is hide effect (on mouseleave event). Icon slide from right to left but not hide.

How can I keep glyphicon and text in one line, and why icon not disappear on mouseleave event?

Comment: Is it what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/5ynbom72/

Comment: @Banzay: whoa :O Simpliest solutions are the best! Please provide it as post (not comment) then I be able to make it as answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define gliphicon just in the html:

```
<div class="hover-me">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; font-size: 15px; line-height: 35px;"></span>&nbsp;<h4>My title</h4>
</div>
```

```js
$('.hover-me').mouseenter(function() {
     $(this).find('.glyphicon').show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 400);
});
$('.hover-me').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('.glyphicon').hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 400);
});
```

To prevent wrapping text in new line make blocks floated left:

```
.hover-me span, .hover-me h4{
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```